# Is it possible to elude the Scala's messy ways of handling tuples as input parameters with Scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to do something like this `List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5).map(_ + _)` to get `List(3, 9)` as a result. But it doesn't work that way.

Does Scalaz provide means to deal with this in a convenient way, unlike the Scala's native "tupled" or pattern matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually think the following is exceptionally convenient—even better than the pattern matching versions in the other answers:

```
List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5) map Function.tupled(_ + _)
```

But I'll be perverse and provide a Scalaz solution to a slightly different problem. Suppose we're working with streams instead of lists, and also suppose we built our stream of pairs by zipping the following two streams:

```
val a = Stream(1, 4)
val b = Stream(2, 5)
```

Scalaz includes an instance of what's called [the "zip list" applicative functor](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) for streams. It's not the default instance, but we can "tag" our streams appropriately and use it like this:

```
scala> import scalaz._, std.stream._
import scalaz._
import std.stream._

scala> streamZipApplicative(Tags.Zip(a), Tags.Zip(b))(_ + _).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 9)
```

And there you go! A Scalaz solution to a vaguely related problem. (I'm only being a little sarcastic—I love this stuff, and the zip list applicative functor is worth knowing about.)

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't have this covered. Yes, the "tupled" solution is fine but as much as a lot of other stuff isn't nearly as neat as it is in Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

Scalaz won't help you.

You can use plain Scala with the answer of @tylerweir (I really like this solution) :

```
scala> val a = List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
a: List[Int] = List(3, 9)
```

OR you can do a more "generic" stuff (it works on any tupple "size") :

```
scala> val a = List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5, (1,2,3)).map(_.productElements.
    collect{case i:Int => i}.sum)
a:List[Int] = List(3,9,6)
```

OR you can use Shapeless (from Miles Sabin : https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) :

```
scala> val a = List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 4).map(_.hlisted.toList.sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something more general than this?

```
scala> val a = List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
a: List[Int] = List(3, 9)
```

Comment: The question was about Scalaz

Comment: is the aim of the exercise to proove that not everything can/needs to be done in scalaz?

Answer (score 1):

Using a small productivity library [embrace](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/embrace) it is possible to do that like so:

```
List(1 -> 2, 4 -> 5).map(_ $$ (_ + _))
```

Comment: Hey, nice "lib"! I wish it would be in standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scalaz to do this, then you are probably looking to do this with Lenses.
See the course [Learning scalaz: Day 11](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day11), and also the lecture by Edward Kmett [Lenses a Functional Imperative](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q) captured on video. On page 42 of [the pdf slides](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByK3AAy5ubqaMTQ3M2FiZTktODQyNi00OTc2LTkwNTgtNzQ2MWE0OWVlZWJk/edit?hl=en_US) Edward explains the use of Lenses with Maps to change them purely functionally.